# rank nodes according to parameters of paths in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 100 nodes, n1, n2, n3 etc which are connected by three different kind of relationships, r1,r2, and r3.  Each of this relationships have a parameter called "weight" which is a number between lets say, 5, 10 and 15.  I need to develop a ranking based on the number of total paths per node and also another ranking based on the weight.  By total paths i mean that if N1-[r1]->n2 and n2-[r1]->n3 and n3-[r3]->n4 then the total number of paths for n1 would be 3.  the value of the ranking by weight would be 5+5+15=25.

Ideally the query would return a list of the nodes ranked.

Is there a way to do that in cypher?

thanks

Comment: Please provide a sample graph via http://console.neo4j.org and share it here.

Comment: here is a graph I made in the console  http://console.neo4j.org/r/r2ooj2. how would i first discover each node and then discover the relationship and then rank the nodes according to the number of relationships? Can it be done with one cypher or do i have to embed the cypher in a routing that loops over the nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this??

```
MATCH (n1:Label {id:1})-[r1]->(n2:Label {id:2})-[r2]->(n3:Label {id:3})-[r3]->()
RETURN n1, 
      SUM(r1.weight+r2.weight+r3.weight) as weight, 
      count(*) as paths
ORDER BY weight desc, paths desc
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  the problem is that i dont know in advance that n1 has a relationship with any other node.  I need to be able to discover every relationshoip that every node has first and then use your solution. ideally i would love to do in a cypher command rather than use java to get each node and loop over them, somehow i imagine that sending a cypher command would be faster than writing java code that would send a bunch of cyphers  and then sort the results.  What do you think?

Comment: Hi I am having some issue please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753192/neo4j-query-for-shortest-path-stuck-do-not-work-if-i-have-2way-relationship-in/35753289#35753289

Answer (score 1):

Try this, of course with some tweaks for your data model:

```
MATCH path=(a:Foo)-[:r1|r2|r3*]->(d:Foo) 
RETURN length(path) as NumberOfStepsInPath, 
       reduce(sum=0, y in 
              extract(x in relationships(path) | x.weight) 
              | sum + y) 
       as TotalCost;
```

So this matches a path from `a` to `d`, on any of the relationship types you specify, `r1|r2|r3`.  The length of the path is easy, that's just `length(path)`.  Summing the weights is a bit more involved.  First, you `extract` the weight attribute from each relationship in the path.  Then you `reduce` the list of weights down to a single `sum`.

Comment: Hi I am having some issue please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753192/neo4j-query-for-shortest-path-stuck-do-not-work-if-i-have-2way-relationship-in/35753289#35753289